# How to separate columns in matlab

Tags: matlab

if you have an array from a for loop

```
for a =1:3;
    for b=1:3;
        for c=1:3;
            disp([a(:) b(:) c(:)])

        end
    end
end
```

and you want to separate each column of the output

to separate each column you need this code: assuming the data stored in 'A' array:

```
yy = A(:,1)
yx = A(:,2)
yz = A(:,3)
and so on...
```

but what if you don't know the size of your array or if you have m x n array? what is the general code to separate column? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
y = [1  1   1   1   1
1   2   3   1   1   
1   0   2   2   1]


[m,n] = size(y)
for i=1:n
   C{i} = y(:,i);
end
```

Now you can access each column via `C(1)`, `C(2)`, `C(3)`, etc. `C` looks like this:

```
C =
{
  [1,1] =
     1
     1
     1
  [1,2] =
     1
     2
     0
  [1,3] = 
     1
     3
     2
}
```

The output of just `C(2)` is:

```
ans =    
{
  [1,1] =
     1   
     2   
     0   
}
```

---

That said, it is probably better to stick with the code that you have to directly access the column from the matrix (`y(:,1)`), instead of creating a bunch of dynamic variables.

Answer (score 0):

How would you manage these columns separated ? It's not a good idea to name them as y1, y2, ... .

If you want to pick up the i-th column, just use y(:, i). That's a lot easier to use.

Comment: @Raldenors I came into this situations before: I get several vectors with the same length n, and want to return them back from a function. So I combined them into a matrix. In my opinion, it's a good idea to represent "collection of vector" with a matrix.

Comment: @Raldenors I guess you need to tell me more about you context. So I can give more precise help.

Comment: please check again my problem